# any pipeline programing example showing efficiency of pipeline

Tags: pipeline

I'm looking for programming example of pipeline where it execute the instruction/code using pipeline technique that could also be executed by nopipeline technique. so that I can see pipeline is better than nopipeline.

any help pls?

Answer (score 1):

Your CPU pretends it does stuff in order, as far as people looking at it as a black box (that sets memory and reads memory) this is what it does. a pipeline is when it does a bit of  every instruction in the pipeline and moves things along in it every cycle.

If your CPU only has one adder, then a second add instruction will stall the pipeline (the first will have to finish), compilers (GCC) are aware of this so use things like instruction scheduling to always keep the CPU busy.

You cannot "turn it off" to see that it is better. Instruction scheduling is one of the cheapest and most beneficial optimisations we can do, you get it free with assignment analysis and stuff.

You really want a book to talk about "before and after", it's also very hard to say "pipelining made this much of an increase" because it depends on what instructions were used, how many ALUs the CPU has, so forth.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

You are right that we can't turn it off to see that it is better. But I want a simple program that does any thing with pipeline and without pipeline i.e. image processing or processing some other jobs..  so that I can put time before and after execution ...and this way i can see that with pipeline (tast division) there is less time taken for execution.. Not CPU level deep , just upper level program.

Comment: @Mark languages abstract you from the machine by design. Remember variables live on the stack and in the heap, in memory. NOT registers.